# How can a unreadable QRCode be generated by CIFilter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I developed an iOS app in Swift 4 with XCode 9.3 with iOS minimum version 10.0  that generate QRCodes to be read by another app (reader app). The app is in production and the data to be shown in the QRCode are sent by the server and are always mongo ObjectIds (12bytes -> 24 digits)

The problem is that sometimes (really rare) the generated QRCodes are broken (unreadable by scanners or reader app) but I can't reproduce it in a development environment. Images were sent by customers.

QRCode Generator:

```
extension String {

    func toQRCode() -> UIImage?{

         let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

         if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator"), let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor") {

             filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

             filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

             colorFilter.setValue(filter.outputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
             colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0), forKey: "inputColor1") // Background
             colorFilter.setValue(CIColor.init(red: 0.12, green: 0.13, blue: 0.15), forKey: "inputColor0")

             let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)

             if let output = colorFilter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                  return UIImage(ciImage: output)
             }
         }
         return nil
    }
}
```

Usage

```
imageView.image = "QRCodeString".toQRCode()
```

**I can see 2 possible causes**

1. Server is sending wrong data (possible invalid chars) to the app randomly, so I can't reproduce it.
2. The data sent by server is ok, but iOS system is generating broken QRCodes randomly.

Case 1: I tried to generate QRCodes with many different possible invalid char, but none generated an invalid QRCode

Case 2: I searched a lot about possible bugs in CIFilter QRCodes, but found nothing about.

**Imagens with problem:**

[image: QRCode1]
[image: QRCode2]

[image: QRCode3]

Sorry about the quality of image 1 and 2, they are photos of the phone.

The server values to the images above are something like "5073c76a23ce3abf0f000001", but I can't figure out what is going on.

Any idea?

Comment: You should be using `isoLatin1` String encoding instead of `ascii`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that, but still I can't reproduce the unreadable codes.